# Document object in ajax response JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try make ajax request to server with two parameters and get from server string:

JavaScript:

```
function getLetterOfResponsibilityNote(selectedCountryCode, selectedIntendedUseType) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Applications/SelectLetterOfRespinsibilityNote",
        cache: false,
        data: { countryCode: selectedCountryCode, intendedUseType: selectedIntendedUseType },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response !== "") {
                alert("1");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And mvc action:

```
[HttpPost]
public string SelectLetterOfRespinsibilityNote(string countryCode, string intendedUseType)
{
  var countryDetails = new List<ContryLetterOfResponsibility>
  {
    new ContryLetterOfResponsibility
  {
    CountryCode = countryCode,
      IntendedUseType = intendedUseType
  }
};

string xml = XmlSerializerUtil(countryDetails);
var country = _countryService.GetLetterOfResponsibilityNotesByCountryCodeList(xml).FirstOrDefault();

if (country != null)
{
  return country.LetterOfResponsibilityNote;
}

return string.Empty;
}
```

I get `response` object in javascript and verify its value. If its value not empty string, I get alert message. If server pass in JavaScript empty string, i get `Document object` in success action NOT EMPTY STRING. What is it?

Comment: What do you mean?  What are you doing to determine the thing that you think is happening?

Comment: Check if you data responsed from server without html-layout. Where your layout cancelling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from an ajax call is an object, not a string. To get your string, you need to use the responseText property. Try this:

```
if (response.responseText !== "")
```

If you are using jQuery, [see this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The success function is passed an argument whose type is either based on the datatype property sent to the .ajax call, or is inferred from the returned data. So, you may want to try explicitly setting datatype: "text" in the ajax object, which should force the response variable to be a string:

```
function getLetterOfResponsibilityNote(selectedCountryCode, selectedIntendedUseType) {
    $.ajax({
        datatype: "text", // <-- added
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Applications/SelectLetterOfRespinsibilityNote",
        cache: false,
        data: { countryCode: selectedCountryCode, intendedUseType: selectedIntendedUseType },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response !== "") {
                alert("1");
            }
        }
    });
}
```